# How to select a dropdown option with selenium Python, if the dropdown is a button?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I have seen multiple threads similar to my question about how to select something from a dropdown menu with Selenium. The ones I have seen involve using Select and select_by_visible_text. I have tried this but get the error:

```
dropdown = Select(web.find_element_by_xpath("my_xpath"))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text('my_text')


UnexpectedTagNameException: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <button>
```

I tried working with ChatGPT and came up with the below, but this also doesn't work. When I print the dropdown options, the only option it sees is the default option that is already selected, even though when I run the program, I can see it click the dropdown and I see the multiple options.

```
# Click on the dropdown button to reveal the options
dropdown = web.find_element_by_xpath('MY_Xpath')
dropdown.click()

# Wait for the dropdown options to be visible
wait = WebDriverWait(web, 10)
dropdown_options = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "MY_Xpath")))

# Print the dropdown options
print("Number of dropdown options:", len(dropdown_options))
for option in dropdown_options:
    print(option.text)
    if option.text == 'My Text':
        option.click()
        break
```

What other ways can I try to select an option from a dropdown menu?

Comment: That looks like a good way to do it, what's wrong with it?

Comment: After the dropdown appears, you should be able to use an XPath to find the option you want, instead of the loop. But I doubt it will make a significant difference.

Comment: The problem is that the options aren't visible. The len of drop_down options is 1 and the option is the default option. It doesn't see the other options. How can I find the Xpath of the option. If I try to right click the option to inspect, the dropdown disappears?

Comment: Without knowing the actual site and its DOM structure, it's really hard to say. Sometimes it can be tricky to reverse-engineer dynamic sites like this.

Comment: Can't provide the site, but this is the element if that helps:
<button lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-combobox__input slds-input_faux slds-combobox__input-value" id="combobox-button-3016" type="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox" data-value="data" aria-label="data2" aria-required="true" aria-controls="dropdown-element-3016" data-position-id="lgcp-1000025"><span lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-truncate">CO</span></button>

Comment: The button isn't important, what's needed are the elements that it makes visible when you click on it.

Comment: Try finding the JavaScript function that's called when you click on it, to see what elements it adds.